# Rotate a surface of revolution into $\Bbb R^4$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, surfaces

I know you can rotate an arc about an axis of revolution to create a surface of revolution that sits in three dimensional space. Can you take the resulting surface of revolution and rotate it to create a shape that sits in four dimensional space?

For example, let two unit circles overlap and take the inner lens shape, and then create a surface of revolution with the axis of rotation being the y-axis. Then how do you rotate this surface of revolution into four dimensional space?

Another example, is to take a circle, rotate it to create a sphere sitting in three dimensional space and then the question would be how to rotate $S^2$ so that it is higher dimensional and sits in four dimensional space.

[image]

Comment: It has to be sitting in $4$-space to begin with.  Similarly, when you rotate about the $y$-axis, you're assuming that there's a third dimension into which you can rotate it.  So yes, if you assume that your three-dimensional solid is sitting in $4$-space, you can rotate it to trace out a four-dimensional solid.

Comment: However, rotations in $\mathbb R^4$ don’t have a fixed axis as they do in $\mathbb R^3$.